# AWS Lambda function executing without printing entire result

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to read content of all the files in a AWS S3 bucket Via AWS Lambda (using Node). I have hardcoded the S3 Key in a array for testing. But, result of following function is only printing partial content.

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    
    exports.handler = async  (event, context,callback) => {
       
       var AllKey=['Key1, 'Key2']
       
       AllKey.forEach(function(element) {
       (async () => {
      try {
        const file = await s3
          .getObject({ Bucket: 'mb2logs', Key: element })
          .promise();
        console.log(file.Body.toString('utf-8'));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })();
        
       })
       

callback(null,{});
};
```

Comment: Does your function timeout? Maybe you need to increase its timeout to give it more time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that execution of lambda might be terminated before all asynchronous operations are finished. You should return a promise from the handler to ensure that asynchronous operations will be finished. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

> For async handlers, you can use return and throw to send a response or error, respectively. Functions must use the async keyword to use these methods to return a response or error.

> If your code performs an asynchronous task, return a promise to make sure that it finishes running. When you resolve or reject the promise, Lambda sends the response or error to the invoker.